# Run awk comand on a remote server through ssh

Tags: bash, awk, ssh, remote-access, ksh

I'm trying to get a specific set of values from a file on a remote server. The command  works fine when executing that through terminal.

**First ssh Command**

`sshpass -p password  ssh -T user@ip`

**Second Awk Command**

`find /opt/Info_Source/*daily* -type f -mtime -1 -exec zcat {} \; 2>/dev/null | awk -F, -v OFS=',' '$5 ~ /Valid/ && length($2) {print $2}'`

but if I combine both of them  in a script

```
#!/bin/ksh
emp_id=`sshpass -p password  ssh -T user@ip -q << EOF
    find /opt/Info_Source/*daily* -type f -mtime -1 -exec zcat {} \; 2>/dev/null | 
    awk -F, '$5 ~ /Valid/ && length($2) {print $2}'
                        exit
                        EOF `
                        
echo "$emp_id" > Request.txt
```

I get this error

```
awk:  ~ /Valid/ && length() {print }
awk:  ^ syntax error
```

Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: This would be simpler if you didn't complicate matters with a command substitution. Just write the output of the command directly to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `awk` variables are expanded as shell variables locally before the script is sent. Quote the here document delimiter to send the here document as-is.

(Also, get rid of the command substitution and just write directly to the file.)

```
#!/bin/ksh

sshpass -p password  ssh -T user@ip -q << 'EOF' > Request.txt
find /opt/Info_Source/*daily* -type f -mtime -1 -exec zcat {} \; 2>/dev/null | 
awk -F, '$5 ~ /Valid/ && length($2) {print $2}'
EOF
```

Comment: well sometimes a simple solution is the best option, indeed it worked fine. thanks for your help